# How to open a PDF file containing a password in the web browser

Tags: vb.net

I currently have a form with button & web browser control I know how to open a normal pdf file but I don't know how to open a pdf containing a password (password by me) so is there any idea about how to do that, please

this is my small code :

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    WebBrowser1.Navigate(Application.StartupPath & "\xxxx\123.pdf")

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Moahammed, there probably is a lot of code in your project we cannot see, so it is difficult to make a meaningful suggestion based on what you have posted. Could you provide more information such as any error messages you receive, exceptions thrown, or other behavior? With your existing code what result do you have now?

Comment: ok i will explain more what i need for example if i use (Foxit Reader SDK Std Control) instead of webbrowser control the code will be like this :  AxFoxitReaderSDK1.OpenFile("AbsolutePath.pdf", "Password")

Comment: "...such as any error messages you receive, exceptions thrown, or other behavior? With your existing code what result do you have now?"

Comment: More specifically, we need an example that can be run...: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve